# Promise not executing then outside but it is inside the function

Tags: reactjs, promise, react-redux, dispatch

I am using a promise to dispatch an asynchronous action in react. I just want to change the properties of an object. The function works. If I wrap the code in a promise and after doing `Promise().then` works but if I do `myFunction(params).then()` the `then is not called` here is my function. (It is recursive):

```js
export function setValue(propertyPath, value, obj) {
  console.log("setting the value")
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // this is a super simple parsing, you will want to make this more complex to handle correctly any path
      // it will split by the dots at first and then simply pass along the array (on next iterations)
      let properties = Array.isArray(propertyPath) ? propertyPath : propertyPath.split(".")

      // Not yet at the last property so keep digging
      if (properties.length > 1) {
        // The property doesn't exists OR is not an object (and so we overwrite it) so we create it
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(properties[0]) || typeof obj[properties[0]] !== "object") obj[properties[0]] = {}
        // We iterate.
        return setValue(properties.slice(1), value, obj[properties[0]])
        // This is the last property - the one where to set the value
      } else {
        // We set the value to the last property
        obj[properties[0]] = value
        console.log("modified object")
        console.log(obj)
        return resolve(obj)
      }
    }
  )
}

export function performPocoChange(propertyPath, value, obj) {
  console.log("we are indeed here")
  return (dispatch) => {
    setValue(propertyPath, value, obj).then((poco) => {
      console.log("poco is here")
      console.log(poco)
      dispatch(changePoco(poco))
    })
  }
}
```

the console shows "we are indeed here" but not "Poco is here" and changePoco (that is the action) is not called. However if I do a `then` right after the brackets of the promises and log it shows the log.

I am not an expert in JS. I am trying really hard and this really got me. Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Since I cannot `edit` my own question being that a *privilege* only a few has I want to state that the log "setting the value" appears in the console and if I put a log right before the return I get the log displayed. It is the `then` part that is not being executed. Many thanks in advance

Comment: You are not `resolve`ing the promise except in the `else` so the `then` doesn't get executed. Also you can edit your own questions (always).

Comment: I recommend avoiding the promise constructor _altogether_ and either use promisified APIs (apis already returning promises) or `Promise.resolve` to create a promise of a fixed value.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminGruenbaum This actually works. Can you write that into a answer so I can mark it as an answer and upvote it? Many many thanks. Lesson learned

Comment: So the solution works because I want to *only* return a promise in the `else` hence there is when I added the Promise.resolve(). Many many thanks for that

Comment: I upvoted Benjamin's suggestion to use a promise library because I think it could help you clarify this logic. Your current implementation is weird to my eyes. Having a function 'setValue' conditionally return a promise is confusing.

Comment: Hi @DevinFields The issue is that Redux only let me to use async functions with middleware with dispatch. I tried to call to functions one after another inside an action and I got an error telling me that. I was doing that to call my APIs and all are working so I figured out I needed a promise which is working now *except* the function without promise return the full object (object + nested properties) but inside the promise only return the last nested properties as the root object. I am investigating that at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not `resolve`ing the promise except in the `else` so the then doesn't get executed.

Comment: Please look at the comments also by @BenjaminGruenbaum on the question for a better understanding. I ended using Promise.Resolve() like he suggested but also I am rewriting the function because it is not right to return a promise just in the else like he said.